# Asymptotic expansion of elliptic integrals of 1st and 2nd kind as m approaches 0

Tags: asymptotics, elliptic-integrals, global-analysis

I am trying to find a two term asymptotic expansion of the following elliptic integrals of first and second kind as $m\to 0$.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-m^2 \sin^2\theta}} d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\sqrt{1-m^2 \sin^2\theta}} d\theta$$

Using the local and global contributions, one can split the integral limits as $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}= \int_{0}^{\lambda} + \int_{\lambda}^{\pi/2}$. While the final result should be independent of $\lambda$, I get otherwise.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We approximate the general integral
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-m^2 \sin^2 \theta   \right)^\alpha d\theta \tag{1}$$

By Taylor developpement
$$
\left(1-m^2 \sin^2 \theta   \right)^\alpha = 1-\alpha \sin^2 (\theta). m^2 +\mathcal{O}(m^4)
$$

As $\left(1-m^2 \sin^2 \theta   \right)^\alpha >0$, we can change the order of integration and limit
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-m^2 \sin^2 \theta   \right)^\alpha d\theta &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-\alpha \sin^2 (\theta). m^2 +\mathcal{O}(m^4)  \right) d\theta \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha \frac{\pi}{4} m^2 + \mathcal{O}(m^4) \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Replace $\alpha = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ to $(2)$, you will get the results.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of the approach using local and global contributions?

Comment: @nchom I don't know why it's necessary to split the integral into 2 parts for this case. It seems to me that this technique is used only when the integrand hasn't unnormal behavior (for example $f(x) \xrightarrow{x\to 0} +\infty$ ) at the lower bounds $x = 0$

Comment: You are right. Thanks.